# Create a Schema object in Mongoose/Handlebars with custom keys/values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I want to create a form to input custom keys and values of an object in an mongo/mongoose schema to eventually see in a handlebars view. See example to better explain. Any help would be great. :)

Mongoose/Mongodb Schema:

```
var docketSchema = new Schema({
  staff: [{ String: String, String: String }]
});
```

Handlebars input view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input value="{{input.staffkey1}}">
    <input value="{{input.staffvalue1}}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input value="{{input.staffkey2}}">
    <input value="{{input.staffvalue2}}">
</div>
```

Comment: The schema should look like `staff: [{ key: String, value: String }]` and in view you would do {{#each staff}} {{key}}:{{value}}{{/each}}

Comment: @Molda Thanks. One other question. To target the array from a form input. Is it the following: <input type="text" id="key" name="key" required value="{{staff.key}}">??

Comment: Well it depends on what you pass to the view. If you pass {staff: [{key:'key1', val:'val1'}, {key:'key2', val:'val2'}]} then in view you do something like {{#each staff}} {{key}}: <input type="text" name="{{key}}" value="{{val}}"> {{/each}}

Comment: @Molda, im using staff : [{ key: string }], my view for my form is {{#each staff}}<input type="text" name="{{key}}" required value="{{key}}">{{/each}} and does not render my form. Thanks.

Comment: How do you pass staff to view? Do you use express, something like  res.render('myView', {staff:[{...}]});

Comment: @Molda, yes I use express. I have a router do a POST method by using req.body to get form values then push to db.   router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {userService.addDocket(req.body, function(err) {
      var vm = {
        input: req.body
      };
      res.redirect('/dockets');
  });
});

Comment: And in /dockets page you want to render it, that's where the problem is, right? So show me res.render in router.get('/dockets'...

Comment: @Molda here it is: router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  var vm = {
    title: 'Create a docket',
    firstName: req.user.firstName
  };
  res.render('dockets/create', vm);
}); see clear example here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907290/target-an-array-in-a-mongo-mongoose-schema-using-a-handlebars-form)

Comment: You showing me GET /create but I asked for GET /dockets since I understand that dockets page is where you want to render the `staff` and where you have the problem. So you need to pass staff to render function like  vm.staff=[{key:"...", val:".."}] If this isn't it then I'm lost sorry

Answer (score 0):

the reason to use mongoose is usually to ensure that your documents have some known keys and to validate new objects so they conform to your schema.

If you explicitly don't want your objects to have the same keys use the schema-type `Mixed` - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html:

```
var docketSchema = new Schema({
   staff: [{}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `strict: false` to your schema to add fields to your schema which are not defined.

```
var docketSchema = new Schema({
    //
}, {strict: false});
```

Nevertheless it is always better to define your fields.