# Target an array in a mongo/mongoose schema using a handlebars form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

.I know I am not targeting correctly my schema because I get an empty array. I want to push my input values in the staff array. It seems like there's limited handlebars documentation on input fields templating. Thanks!

My Schema:

```
var docketSchema = new Schema({
  companyName: string,
  address: string,
  staff: [{ manager: String, 
            receptionist: String 
        }]
});
```

My handlebars template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required value="{{input.address}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="companyName" name="companyName" required value="{{input.companyName}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="manager" name="manager" required value="{{input.staff.manager}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="receptionist" name="receptionist" required value="{{input.staff.receptionist}}">
</div>
```

My route:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  userService.addDocket(req.body, function(err) {
      var vm = {
        input: req.body
      };
      res.redirect('/dockets');
  });
});
```

My console:

```
[ { companyName: 'Acme',
    address: 'New York',
    staff: [] } ]
```

My addDocket method:

```
exports.addDocket = function(docket, next) {
    var newDocket = new Docket({
      companyName: docket.companyName,
      address: docket.address,
      staff: docket.staff
    });

    newDocket.save(function(err) {
      next(null);
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are implementing the `addDocket()` method?

Comment: @chridam, here you go: router.get('/dockets', function(req, res, next) {
    Docket.find({}, function(err, dockets){
      var model = dockets.map(function (doc){

               return {
                  title: 'List of Dockets',
                  companyName: doc.companyName,
                  address: doc.address,
                  staff: doc.staff
               };
        });
      console.log(model);
      res.render('dockets/index', { "doclist": model, "firstName": req.user.firstName });
    });
});

Comment: @chridam, but isnt this irrelevant since it is the form submission that doesnt properly submit to the schema from the begining?

Comment: @chridam, here's my addDocket method: exports.addDocket = function(docket, next) {
    var newDocket = new Docket({
      companyName: docket.companyName,
      address: docket.address,
      staff: docket.staff
    });
    
    newDocket.save(function(err) {
      next(null);
    });
};

Comment: Please use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33907290/edit) link to add those details to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @chridam, sorry about that, its there now.

Answer (score 0):

In your handlebars template, try creating the form elements with arrays as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required value="{{input.address}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="companyName" name="companyName" required value="{{input.companyName}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="manager" name="staff[manager]" required value="{{input.staff.manager}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="receptionist" name="staff[receptionist]" required value="{{input.staff.receptionist}}">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i still get a blank array. Maybe its how the method and schema are communicating?